# Sending string after register method asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm new in asp.net Core and I do a Register using Identity

So my method is something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            MaidenName = model.MaidenName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Abbreviation = model.Abbreviation,
            UserName = model.Username,
            Email = model.Email,
            Pin = model.Pin
        };

        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (!result.Succeeded) return BadRequest();
        var userRole = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "super-admin");
        var claims = new[]
        {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "super-admin")
        };

        var claimResult = await _userManager.AddClaimsAsync(user, claims);

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var exception = e;
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

Method works correctly, it create user succesfull, but when it is created it return me a blank page, my question is how can I add to this Blank page only a label saying "Success"?

Answer (score 1):

Well, when you use

```
return Ok();
```

You are returning a HTTP 200 code with a null body. That's meant for APIs, not web applications.

You have a couple of common options:

1. Use AJAX to do the call, instead of POSTing back the form. In the success handler you can decide what to do. This way you keep the `return Ok();` as it is.
2. Create a View (`"RegisterSuccess.cshtml"`) or something like that) and use `return View("RegisterSuccess");` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to return a json object like:

```
{
    success: true
}
```

I recommend to create an object to use within `Ok` method:

```
return Ok(new { success: true });
```

Then, the result in the *blank page* looks like this:

```
{success:true}
```

Or just a string:

```
return Content("Success");
```